# Flushing pages to disk in order

Tags: linux, file-io, mmap, page-caching, fsync

Is there a way to impose the order in which pages are flushed from memory to disk in Linux, except updating pages in the desired order and performing `fsync()`/`msync()` after *each* page update, separately? Relates to [the linux page cache flush order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707442/the-linux-page-cache-flush-order), where I haven't found a clear answer also.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: @JohnZwinck it is the only way to prevent data store corruption, when update touches several pages. Even if I perform `fsync` after each query, if page flushing order is not guaranteed, data store could be corrupted on power loss during flushing. Otherwise I can distinguish the page to be flushed last => guarantees other pages involved into the update already flushed.

Comment: Something to consider is if you can revise your storage/update mechanism in some way, e.g. so that you write a bunch of "pending" updates, then flush once, then write a "commit message" and flush again.  The "commit message" would be very small, perhaps just updating a counter, so it could be guaranteed to exist on a single page.  This might give the safety you need with the performance you desire.